# Why do I get two different ratings for same position (López Opening: Morphy Defense, Caro Variatio) on chess.com?

Tags: engines, analysis

I've been trying to get back into chess a bit, and noticed the option to practice certain positions - but I've been puzzled by the rating when playing a "Friendly" game (which gives you feedback for your moves).

During practice, the move that's considered "excellent" is considered an "inaccuracy" in the exact same game against a computer.

I'm not sure about chess notation, I'll try to supply pictures.

The position I reach as black is this one, trying to figure out my next best move:

[Ruy López Opening: Morphy Defense, Caro Variation, 5.Bb3](https://www.chess.com/openings/Ruy-Lopez-Opening-Morphy-Defense-Caro-Variation-5.Bb3)

[image]

If I practice this position ([here](https://www.chess.com/practice/custom?fen=r1bqkbnr/2pp1ppp/p1n5/1p2p3/4P3/1B3N2/PPPP1PPP/RNBQK2R%20b%20KQkq%20-%202%205)), Bishop to b5 is rated as "good"

[image]

But if I do the exact same move in my own game, it's rated as "inaccuracy"

[image]

The ratings also seem fairly different (+0.99 vs +0.39). What am I missing here? Is this move good, or inaccurate? Why do I get two fairly different responses for the exact same game position - does it rate differently according to the opponents Elo rating? Or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is very likely due to a different engine search depth.
The same effect occurs on lichess, when you request an engine analysis after the game directly vs. when you copy it into a lichess study first. Games in studies are analyzed deeper and engine evaluations can differ.
Chess.com typically uses pretty low depth (e.g. 18). When analyzing moves live on chess.com, I have noticed that annotations also sometimes change when replaying the move, suggesting that the position has been calculated deeper, necessitating a change in evaluation.